# Scrapy importing XML feed of 100mb - Memory Error

Tags: python, linux, performance, memory, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape a 100mb XML feed on an Amazon EC2 instance. I am stuck however because when it runs it talks about a memory error. The coder I am working with suggests breaking the 100mb file down into more manageable chunks but I am sure there must be a better way to do this.

Log:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/iterators.py", line 22, in xmliter
        text = body_or_str(obj)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/response.py", line 22, in body_or_str
        return obj.body_as_unicode() if unicode else obj.body
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 62, in body_as_unicode
        self._cached_ubody = html_to_unicode(charset, self.body)[1]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/w3lib/encoding.py", line 173, in html_to_unicode
        return enc, to_unicode(html_body_str, enc)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/w3lib/encoding.py", line 118, in to_unicode
        return data_str.decode(encoding, 'w3lib_replace')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
    exceptions.MemoryError: 

2013-08-08 17:53:29+0000 [site] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-08-08 17:53:29+0000 [site] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 241,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 103257370,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 8, 17, 53, 29, 166687),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
     'log_count/ERROR': 1,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'spider_exceptions/MemoryError': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 8, 17, 53, 26, 375069)}
2013-08-08 17:53:29+0000 [site] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

My question is, is there anything I can do to make it so I can process that 100mb file without  running into memory issues?

Comment: What does "it talks about a memory error (leak)" mean? The traceback you showed us doesn't say anything about a leak. It's quite possible to have a `MemoryError` without any leaks; if you're actually trying to use more memory than you have, even if you're going to dispose of it properly, it's still an error.

Comment: Meanwhile, what's the actual code that raises this exception? And what version of scrapy are you using?

Comment: Original post edited to reflect this (re: memory error). I am using the most recent version of scrapy. I am not sure how about how to isolate the specific bit of code causing this.

Comment: Also, what EC2 type are you running on? If you're trying to use, say, a t1.micro with 600MB, decoding 100MB of cp1252 bytes into 400MB of Unicode is going to fail; your only option is to use a larger instance, or do it in pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrapy` always tries to decode your entire input data to Unicode. On a typical wide-Unicode build, this means a 100MB HTML page will expand to 400MB.

So, how can you get around that?

- Use a larger (and 64-bit) EC2 instance.
- Use a different library that doesn't need to decode your entire input data the way scrapy does.
- Use Python 3.3, or a narrow-Unicode build of Python 2.x, so your Unicode ends up only 100MB or 200MB instead of 400MB.
- Read and process the data in chunks.